# How to debug a Titanium application?

Tags: debugging, titanium

I have started learning titanium framework.I was making application into iphone.I have made application and assigned breakpoints to it for debug, but somehow debug was not working....

I have downloaded titanium developer tool and started launching of application from tool,breakpoints were set at titanium studio,but it was not stopping at debug point...

please help me out with any example or any useful link and suggest me debugging steps....

Thanks, 
Mishal Shah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://preview.appcelerator.com/studio/

You must have 1.7 installed for advanced debugging but they advise against using it in a release since it's still not a stable version.